# Helix with a helix as its axis

Tags: geometry, terminology, curves

Does anyone know if there is a name for the curve which is a helix, which itself has a helical axis? I tried to draw what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Standard terms are 'super-helix' or 'super-coil'.  See DNA.

Comment: But DNA is a double helix, which is a different thing from this.

Comment: @aml the term supercoil includes other forms of secondary coiling, such as plectonemes, which are different from the example OP gave. So maybe it is a subset of supercoils.

Comment: @user50229: True, but DNA also super-coils. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5zFOScowqo

Comment: Informally, people might understand the analogy with a telephone wire

Comment: @Jyrki I don't see anywhere in the thread where the name of the curve is given.

Comment: Ah! You wanted a name rather than a parametrization. Ok, sorry.

Comment: I believe this is the shape of a tungsten light bulb filament.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to [**this journal article**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437100005720), we may call it a *doubly-twisted helix* or generally a *multiply-twisted helix*.

[image]

Answer (score 40):

For a light bulb the wire is called a "coiled coil filament" in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Coiled_coil_filament) Wikipedia article.

[image: coiled coil filament]

The German word is "Doppelwendel" (roughly translated: double screw).

Comment: fascinating....

Comment: @rschwieb Even more fascinating: Tungsten is brittle, and still they manage to coil it like that. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIGqBb3iZPo

Answer (score 22):

I don't believe there is a standard term. Nevertheless, MathWorld calls the resulting curve a ["slinky"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Slinky.html).

[image: slinky]

Of course, one can have a "slinky" of a "slinky":

[image: superslinky]

Comment: Very funny. Improved barbedwire!

Comment: Since "slinky" = "superhelix", the last one can be called a **superslinky**?

Comment: Personally, I prefer the parametrization like this:
\begin{bmatrix}
  a\cos t+r\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin t \sin nt-\cos t \cos nt \right) \\
  a\sin t+r\left(\sin t \cos nt-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos t \sin nt \right) \\
  bt+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} r\sin nt
\end{bmatrix} with the parent/primary helix as:
\begin{bmatrix}
  a\cos t \\  a\sin t \\  bt
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: @Ng, yeah, I'd have made an arclength parametrization of the helix first so that the normal and binormal vectors would come out nice...

Comment: P.S. The plots were of course generated with *Mathematica*.

Comment: J.M. Ng's formula is ok for the first iteration because the natural parameter is a constant multiple of $t$ (as I'm sure you know), so simple normalization of the normal/binormal will do just fine. You are, of course, right about the need to use arclength parametrization in all the succeeding iterations - I don't want to do that with paper&pencil :-)

Comment: "I don't want to do that with paper & pencil" - I'm sure you don't, @Jyrki. *Mathematica* actually gags if I try to iterate beyond the fifth, as the required Frenet frame expression is incredibly complex.

Answer (score 8):

A corresponding construction on the torus is called an "iterated torus knot", so perhaps "iterated helix" would be a good name. I don't know of any standard name.

Answer (score 5):

*Coiled coil* as others also stated. More length is packed in a small volume. Used for electric bulb filaments, toroidal transformer primaries etc. Polar orbits of sun synchronous satellites around earth/sun is another example if the inner coil has no torsion.

EDIT1

A constant vector component of binormal   is added to central coil vector if helicoids are to be defined as a surface... as a set of connected coils.